# Find ios data path location in Unity3d

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, ios10

I have the following problem: I have written a C++ Library for iOS, which I am using in Unity3d, which works so far. Now I would like to open a xml File inside my Library. So I have to pass the path to the xml file to the c++ library, but I don't know how to get the right path. The Unity3d data path I would get with Application.dataPath, but I would need the location of the data folder that you see in your folder structure when you create an iOS Xcode project.
What I am doing: Unity Build -> Xcode opens -> I copy the xml file to the data folder. How can I pass exactly that path of this data folder?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers

Comment: You need to Google *"Passing string from C# to C++"*. You need to do your work before somebody can hep you. There are just many answers to this out there.

Comment: I know how to pass a string, but I don't know how to get the location of the data folder of the iOS application, but I think I will use the objective-c function to get the location of the data folder, if it doesn't work from Unity3d or the C++ library.

Comment: I don't think changing the title of this question will help you at-all. You have to modify the question and add exactly where the xml file is location in your project. You also have to add the C# code you use to pass the path to C++ and the C++ code that receives the string path. You will likely not get help until you do this since no one knows where you are stuck.